# Creating a new content type places random options on the content type page

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

I've created a new content type with multiple radio buttons.

Like this:

> 1) Is this your first survey?
>       o yes   o no
>       2) Is the color yellow?
>       o yes   o no
>       3) Tomorrow is friday?
>       o yes   o no

But when I go to the content type page I see this:

> 1) Is this your first survey?
>       o yes   o no
>       `>` Authoring information
>       2) Is the color yellow?
>       o yes   o no
>       3) Tomorrow is friday?
>       o yes   o no
>       `>` Publishing options

The "Authoring Information" and "Publishing options" just appear randomly, and they don't exist in the "manage fields" area. Where are these options coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Those options are shown to the administrator users by default; if you log in as a regular user, you don't see them. You can enable and disable them in permissions "node / administer content".

Comment: hmm, but why do they show up in the middle of my fields?